# How to get a brief description for every executable in a folder?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, terminal, command-line-interface

My Unix system has lots of executables under the usr/bin folder. I want to get a brief description of each executable, similar to the brief description shown by the man command under the "NAME" section. The final output would be a list like this (in alphabetical order):

```
ls - list directory contents
sort - sort or merge records (lines) of text and binary files
wc - word, line, character, and byte count
```

How can I do it on bash?

Comment: look at whatis ls ?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With GNU find, xargs and whatis:

```
find /usr/bin/ -executable -printf '%f\0' | xargs -0 whatis 2>/dev/null
```

Output (e.g.):

```
ls (1)               - list directory contents
sort (1)             - sort lines of text files
wc (1)               - print newline, word, and byte counts for each file
find (1)             - search for files in a directory hierarchy
xargs (1)            - build and execute command lines from standard input
whatis (1)           - display one-line manual page descriptions
```